# Auto increment property with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have an existing Object - I cannot modify - that we're looking to add a custom ID property to during serialization.

```
TestEntity {
  ...
  @JsonProperty("addresses")
  List<Address> addresses;
  ...
}
Address {
   // NOTE NO ID
   String street
   String number
   ...
}
```

Ideally, we'd like to be able to turn this into XML, with an ID associated to each `Address` object.

```
...
<Addresses>
  <Address id=1>
   <street>...</street>
   ...
  </Address>
  <Address id=2>
   <street>...</street>
   ...
  </Address>
  <Address id=3>
   <street>...</street>
   ...
  </Address>
</Addresses>
```

I'm currently looking at a custom mixin class, but didn't know if there was a better option.

Any ideas on how to better solve this?

===============================================

Edit:  Currently, we're serializing based on the TestEntity, so I cannot create a wrapping entity.

```
...
objectMapper.writeAsString(testEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don‘t get it. Why don‘t you use Inheritance?

```
class IdentifiableAddress extends Address {
    private long id;

    // Getter/Setter...
}
```

I am probably missing something. What does „not modifiable“ mean? You can‘t modify the object or the class?

Comment: We cannot since we are serializing/deserializing using ObjectMapper in our existing code.  I am trying to easily manipulate the serialization process, not any of the entities.  There are over 10,000 entities we would have to update

Comment: I cannot modify the root class, nor any of the property classes contained within the root entity (TestEntity)

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom mixin?

```
@JsonAppend(
attrs = {
    @JsonAppend.Attr(value = "id")
}) 
public static class WithIdMixin {}
```

And then:

```
mapper.addMixIn(POJO.class, WithIdMixin.class);

ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(POJO.class).withAttribute("id", someGlobalLong++);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, however I would have to create an ObjectWriter for each instance I'm looking to update.  There are currently 9,901 entities.  I was hoping for something that can accept a generic Object which would be applied to all entites

Comment: You could still use Reflection API to get the Pojo class dynamically before serialization and would only need to write the line once. I know, performance might be an issue, but I am running out of ideas 

Comment: I'd need to get all 9,901 classes.  Any examples of doing this out there?

Comment: Another thought is to apply the mixin only on the elements of a `List`, using the index of the element as the id value